# What does Farrakhan mean by "false Jews"?

Tags: united-states, ideology, terminology, antisemitism

In a speech of his, Farrakhan [referenced](https://www.splcenter.org/fighting-hate/extremist-files/group/nation-islam) "false Jews":

> These false Jews promote the filth of Hollywood that is seeding the American people and the people of the world and bringing you down in moral strength. … It's the wicked Jews, the false Jews, that are promoting lesbianism, homosexuality.

My guess is that this is a reference to the [khazar myth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khazar_hypothesis_of_Ashkenazi_ancestry), but I couldn't find any specific quote from Farrakhan confirming this (I was also unable to find the full speech the above quote is from, which might give more insight).

Are there speeches or writings from Farrakhan where he goes into detail about what he considers "false Jews" (and on the other hand, who he considers to be "real" Jews)?

Comment: Comments deleted. Please don't use comments to answer the questions or to start political discussions. For more informations about what comments should or should not be used for, please check [the help article about the commenting privilege](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be three classes of people that Farrakhan considers to be "real Jews":

1. The ancient people of Israel: The prophets, and Judges, and Hebrews, perhaps back to Moses, Abraham or even Noah. "True Faith in the laws and Teaching of Abraham, Jesus and Muhammad is not dirty"
2. Jewish people who agree with his homophobic viewpoint and don't engage with the US government: "You are not real Jews.... You are the synagogue of Satan, and you have wrapped your tentacles around the U.S. government"
3. Jews who engage with Scientology and embrace Dianetics. “All white people should flock to L. Ron Hubbard. [...] You can still be a Jew, but you won’t be a satanic Jew.”

Comment: Note. Nothing in this answer should be understood to condone, accept or apologise for any aspect of Farrakhan's ideology.

Comment: Can you tell us the source where you copied these quotes from?

Comment: Wikipedia and the links at the bottom of the wikipeida article

Comment: Which wikipedia article? Which links? I think you should edit your answer and add who said these things, when, where and if it is relevant in which context.